# Probabilistic soft logic (PSL) through maven downloading error

Tags: java-8, maven-3

I am trying to download PSL (Probabilistic Soft Logic :Groove for Intermediate Users)  through Maven but I am not able to download it it gives me the following Error
**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (edu.umd.cs:psl-archetype-example:1.2.1**
I am using windows and following the procedure as stated in this
https://github.com/linqs/psl/wiki/Installing-examples

My maven command is as follows
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=psl-archetype-example -DarchetypeRepository=https://scm.umiacs.umd.edu/maven/lccd/content/repositories/psl-releases/ -DarchetypeGroupId=edu.umd.cs -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.1

I am using Apache Maven 3.3.9 and Java 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

The instructions in this page, also say that: `The Windows shell (CMD.EXE) doesn't accept line continuations ('\'), so remove those and enter the command all on one line.`. When you copy and paste check that there are two `\` symbols. Remove then and it will work.

Comment: I removed ('\') symbols as you could see above the command and also I entered this command in one line by removing two ('\') symbols. But I don't know why it's not working .

Comment: Could you please reproduce what you did?

Comment: **mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=psl-archetype-example -DarchetypeRepository=https://scm.umiacs.umd.edu/maven/lccd/content/repositories/psl-releases/ -DarchetypeGroupId=edu.umd.cs -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.1**                                                                          I made the syntax like this above as stated above and run this command by using cmd.in windows